# pAdmni 4 does not connect to remote postgres on redhat-- netstat shows no bindings to TCP?

Tags: networking, iptables, postgresql

Had a field day installing postgres and configuring it correctly. Opened the iptables to allow connection to and from my computer to the remote server. Change the .conf files to make psql listen out for any connection. Still cannot connect. Using netstat shows something peculiar.

```
netstat -nlp | grep 5432
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1001 but you should be root.)
tcp             0        0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6            0        0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM         LISTENING     21219    -                    /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM         LISTENING     21217    -                    /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

the first line, tcp, usually ends with something like `28432/postgres`, but it's empty `-` leads me to believe nothing is bound to the tcp socket.

I can run `psql` just fine and create tables from within my ssh connection from my computer.

Comment: Did you modify `pg_hba.conf`to allow access from your remote machine?

Comment: `host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               ident`

added this line

Comment: The output of your netstat command isn't any special. The message "No info could be read..." says you must be root to get the requested information - just `sudo netstat -nlp` should help.

Comment: `ident` as authentification method requests that a) you are the same user on the client as you are on the server and b) the server has access to the "ident service" on the client (see [ident protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ident_protocol)). You could try `md5` and use password authentification; or (for testing purpose only!!!), set it to `trust` to see if the connection works at all. And look into /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-*-main.log on the server for any errors.

Comment: And as your server listens to IPv6 as well, your client maybe tries IPv6 and therefore there should also be an entry for that in pg_hba.conf, e.g. `host all all ::/0 md5`(or whatever method you chose).

Comment: Great guess. I added the line and modified the authentication protocol. No dice. 

Here's netstat output as root (showing only postgres instances): `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1613/postgres`



`tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      1613/postgres`

active unix domain sockets: `unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8684     1613/postgres        /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432`

`unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8682     1613/postgres        /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`

Comment: it looks like its running and listening just fine. Will check logs.

Comment: LOG: `database is ready to receive connections`. Other than a few logs of my command line queries, no report of attempted connections are in the log.

Comment: Your server seems to run fine, and you should be able to run `psql -h localhost` on the server (should thus use tcp, not sockets). One more thing to check is the network connection from client to server (depends on the OS of your client; on linux I would suggest `nmap` to check if the server port is reachable. Don't know how to do that on Windows).

Comment: I installed and ran `nmap -p 5432 -sV localhost` and successfully returned the postgres instance running: `5432/tcp open  postgresql PostgreSQL DB`

However it did return a warning I'm unfamiliar with:
`1 service unrecognized despite returning data.`:`SF-Port5432-TCP:V=6.40%I=7%D=12/2%Time=584243B0%P=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu%SF:r(SMBProgNeg,85,"E\0\0\0\x84SFATAL\0C0A000\0Munsupported\x20frontend\x2SF:0protocol\x2065363\.19778:\x20server\x20supports\x201\.0\x20to\x203\.0\SF:0Fpostmaster\.c\0L1782\0RProcessStartupPacket\0\0");`

Comment: This is OK, as a) postgresql does not understand the request issued by `nmap` (says: `unsupported frontend protocol`), and b) nmap does not understand this answer. I think I did not clearly advise: You should run `nmap`on the client to see if the network connection works and there is no firewall blocking port 5432.

Comment: The command `nmap -sT -Pn -vv <ip_address>`, with the actual remote IP of course, showed that the remote server has port `22/tcp` open, `80/tcp` closed, and `443/tcp` closed. Definitely no postgres port. Which is odd considering I added this rule to the `iptable`.

Comment: So I can't help any more. Maybe there are firewalls or sort of restricted VPN between client and server. As port 22 is open you may try running pgadmin on the server, having X11 tunneled (`ssh -X`)